# C++ "Compiler" with preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

So we have an assignment in which we create something like a compiler for a pseudo language.

Example:

```
PROGRAM_BEGIN
...             //code
VAR(name) = NUMBER(2.3)
PROGRAM_END
```

We have to handle this with the preprocessor and turn it into c++ code.

Example:

```
#define PROGRAM_BEGIN int main(){
#define PROGRAM_END return 1;}
```

What I have trouble with is that we have to support code like:

```
VAR(name) = NUMBER(1)+NUMBER(2.5)
```

After much thought I had a couple of ideas but nothing has worked so far (for example, use variables with dynamically created names). I guess that with some proper data handling, I've already made plans to organize the input into classes and use of the operator overload could help make this work but I still can't see the big picture.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly are you asking for? If you are looking for a way to express `VAR(name)` with preprocessor you should take look at preprocessor macros. In this case `#define VAR(name) int name` should do the trick. Actually `int` doesn't do well here. I guess using floating point and doing implicit conversion or using union would be the way. But can't tell without actual requirements.

Comment: yup i've done that, however if u do that NUMBER(22) + NUMBER(11) will become int x = 22; + int x = 11; and this will not run...

Comment: `1` or `2.5` are already a numbers, so `NUMBER` macro doesn't need to do anything else

Comment: you could use `auto` in `VAR`

Comment: `#define VAR(name) int name` and `#define NUMBER(number) number` if you do `VAR(x) = NUMBER(1) + NUMBER(3)`, preprocessor will translate to `int x = 1 + 3`

Comment: oh it seems i was overthinking things, thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (the `cout` is for debug only):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define PROGRAM_BEGIN   int main(){
#define PROGRAM_END     return 1;}
#define VAR(x)          auto x
#define NUMBER(x)       x

PROGRAM_BEGIN
VAR(name) = NUMBER(1) + NUMBER(2.5);
cout << name << endl;
PROGRAM_END
```

By using `auto` you don't need to worry if `VAR` is an `int` or `float`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer made me understand that the code i had inserted into my #define VAR(ID) should go before the auto ID because otherwise it will not compile